# Natural Join Explanation

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

I am a student trying to learn Microsoft SQL and I am frustrated that I cannot understand how natural join works. I have a problem with a solution but I cannot understand how this solution was created through natural join. My friend sent my his old solution but cant remember how he got the result. I really want to figure out how this natural join works. Can someone please explain how this answer was achieved?

The question taken from "Database Design, Application, and Administration 6th Ed.:

12. Show the result of a natural join that combines the Customer and OrderTbl tables.

[image: Tables]

[image: Solution]

Edit: The book doesn't give a query statement on how to get the results for the natural join in the chapters I have read so far. Which makes things much more confusing for me as I cannot simply add the table and send a query.

Edit2: The reason why some entries in the order table have null values is because the question is implying that some orders were processed through the internet. A friend of mine told me that was the reason why he got the question right opposed to some people who argued against it. :S

Comment: Have you tried google? This is a basic `JOIN` example. And I'm missing a Customer table in your Tables.

Comment: Microsoft SQL? If you mean SQL Server, be prepared for an answer involving `INNER JOIN` because [SQL Server's T-SQL lacks](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/153679/natural-join-and-using-clause-in-joins) a `NATURAL JOIN` operator.

Comment: Forget about natural join. It's a stupid construction that never, ever should be used.

Comment: @user3807468 Customer table is missing

Comment: @onedaywhen The book uses Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, so I am limited to this for the textbook and class.

Comment: @jarlh: haha, a bit like saying, "Forget about the Relational Model, it's stupid and should never have been invented. Stick to SQL."

Comment: @onedaywhen, not really, but when writing code most people agree that select * should be avoided (to be forward compatible.) A natural join's result may change completely if a column is added to one of the tables, having a name that already exists in the other table. That's why I never use it when writing code.

Comment: @jarlh: they are taking about the concept of natural join as a learning exercise, not SQL Server's `NATURAL JOIN` operator (hint: doesn't exist) in a production environment where some strange and unbridled change control process is taking place. Note the sequence of events: natural join is discovered/invented in the relational model -> `NATURAL JOIN` is introduced late to the SQL Standard -> `NATURAL JOIN` implemented by vendors newer to the market -> new users adopt useful functionality more aligned to the relational model (old guard warn about dangers etc).

Comment: @jarlh, In relational terms all joins are natural joins. The defects of SQL syntax do not invalidate the underlying concept - in fact those defects just underline the importance of understanding the fundamentals so that you can understand where SQL errs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read your question correctly, you are trying to learn two concepts at the same time.  The first is INNER JOIN (sometimes called equijoin).  The second is natural join.

It's easier to explain natural join, assuming you already know how INNER JOIN works.  A natural join is simply an equijoin where the column names indicate to you what the join condition ought to be.  In your case, the fact that CustNo appears in both tables is the only clue you need in order to devise the correct join condition.  You also include the join field only once in the result.

Column names are actually quite arbitrary, and could have been made very different in this case.  for example, if the column Customer.CustNo had been named Customer.ID instead, you wouldn't be able to do a natural join.

for a correct solution in your case, see the answer provided by JamieC.

Comment: BTW, there are INNER JOINs that are not equijoins.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want the query which will result in the final table in your question here it is,

```
SELECT
 o.OrdNo,
 o.OrdDate,
 o.EmpNo,
 o.CustNo,
 c.CustFirstName
 c.CustLastName,
 c.CustCity,
 c.CustSatate,
 c.CustZip,
 c.CustBal
FROM OrderTbl o
  INNER JOIN Customer c
  ON o.CustNo = c.CustNo
ORDER BY c.CustNo
```

So, by way of explanation; this query selects all data from `Customer` and `OrderTbl` joining the two using `CustNo` which is the primary key (presumably) in `Customer` and a foreign key in `OrderTbl`. The ordering of the result is a little more tricky, and based almost purely on guesswork, I suspect the result is ordered by `CustNo` as well.

The `Employee` table does not feature at all in the result, however as the `OrderTbl` table has some blanks for `EmpNo`, you would almost certainly want a `LEFT JOIN`/`RIGHT JOIN` (as appropriate) if you wanted to retrieve any information about the employee from the orders table.

Comment: The problem is  that the chapter didn't cover the query statement for it. The next couple of problems are plagued with similar questions. :(

My next best bet is to move onto the next chapters and try to find the solution but I feel like it defeats the purpose of understanding these queries. But this book is such stupid in explaining this in my opinion.

Thanks for the query though, would upvote if i had 15 rep D:

Comment: @user3807468 . . . Or find a different book.

Comment: @user3807468 I agree with Gordon - get a better book. But Im not sure I understood your point. Is there something my answer does not cover? I am happy to update with more info if I knew what you were after.

Comment: @user3807468: "joining the two using CustNo which is...": did you notice in this explanation the writer didn't think it necessary to qualify with the important point, "using equality operator"? This is because most (all?) the time you want to be using a equality operator between data of the same type. `NATURAL JOIN` takes this sensible approach one stage further by implying that columns with the same name should be used for the join, without the user having to state the obvious to the system.

Comment: @jamiec I have read through your explanation carefully but I am still confused, why does the sequence of the order numbers come in from reverse but retain the same sequence as customer number? Is this the default output for most cases?

Comment: @user3807468 see update regarding the order of results.

Answer (score 0):

MS SQL Server doesn't support NATURAL JOIN. However, if you were using a platform that would support it, a simple:

```
SELECT * FROM Customer NATURAL JOIN OrderTbl;
```

should do the trick.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Natural_join is quite good.